# Striping strings in rows of dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a dataset which consist of around 6 millions urls (rows),
I'm trying to strip off the protocol part of every url ( https://, http://, ftp://) and also want to remove ('www.'), applying that for each row or each url
I applied the next command which works fine:

```
df['url'] = df['url'].str.replace('http://', "")
df['url'] = df['url'].str.replace('https://', "")
df['url'] = df['url'].str.replace('ftp://', "")
df['url'] = df['url'].str.replace('www.', "")
```

but it is a naive approach I guess, and I'm trying to replace those lines with one more efficient line of code, but my attempts didnt work well so far.

can you provide me with a better solution, maybe .apply function or lambda ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `replace` with dictionary instead of `str.replace`

```
df.url.replace({
    'http://': '', 
    'https://': '', 
    'ftp://': '', 
    'www\.': ''
}, regex=True)
```

Note: Since `regex` flag is `True` be careful while creating strings.